# How to add the item "run to line in Python interactive window" in vscode to the right click menu?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am writing python in visual studio code on a new computer.

However, there are items missing in the right click menu that were available on the visual studio code for my previous computer [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdwFk.png). Includes "run from line in Python interactive window", "run selection/line in Python interactive window" and "run to line in Python interactive window".

Is there any setting that I missed for visual studio code?

Comment: I'd check what extensions you had installed in your previous instance of Visual Studio Code, and make sure those are installed on your new computer. You can probably just migrate your configuration files, to ensure everything is ported over. These options are almost certainly exposed by an optional extension, such as the (excellent) [Microsoft Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

Go to the extension settings of python, then find the item ["Send Selection To Interactive Window"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeX7n.png) and toggle on.